# "truffle test" says "assert.rejects" is not a function even it is Node 10

Tags: truffle, nodejs, truffle-test, docker

As per [the official documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/assert.html#assert_assert_rejects_asyncfn_error_message), `assert.rejects` was added since Node v10.0.0.

Also, the node console confirms that:

[image]

even though, `truffle test` throws this error:

```
 TypeError: assert.rejects is not a function
```

Because I wrote this snippet in my unit-tests:

```
  await assert.rejects(async () => {
    await this.contract.createToken(...info, 1, {from: accounts[0]});
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by importing `assert` explicitly at the top of the test file:

```
const assert = require('assert');
```